# Alternative Way to Count Frequency between two lists without count

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have created the following code to check the frequency from the first list compared to the second without using count:

```
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
frequency = [0,0,0]
for i in range(len(F)):
    for num in N:
        if F[i] == num:
            frequency[i]+=1
print('4 occurs in N', frequency[0], 'times')
print('7 occurs in N', frequency[1], 'times')
print('2 occurs in N', frequency[2], 'times')
print()
```

The code outputs correctly:

```
4 occurs in N 2 times
7 occurs in N 1 times
2 occurs in N 3 times
```

Is there another way to do this without using `count`? I was trying a `while`-loop but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "without using Count" ? you mean the `.count(item)` method from a sequence ?

Comment: He means `collections.Count` type

Comment: @Adirio That's `collections.Counter`, not `collections.Count`.

Comment: yes without using count or counter, it is just an exercise I am not using this in the real world, just for learning alternative ways

Comment: Yes, was just a Typo, I still think he refers to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to store the frequencies:

```
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
# Create the initial frequency dictionary
frequency = {}
for item in F:
    frequency[item] = 0

# Count the occurences
for item in N:
    if item in frequency:
        frequency[item] += 1

# Print the occurences
for item in F:
    print('{} occurs in N {} times'.format(item, frequency[item]))
print()
```

Or if you prefer it to be shorter:

```
frequency = dict.fromkeys(N, 0)
for item in N:
    frequency[item] += 1
for item in F:
    print('{} occurs in N {} times'.format(item, frequency[item]))
print()
```

Comment: I added some optimizations as edits, please accept them. They are using dict comprehension for the initial creation and dict views for printing

Comment: @Adirio The printing was done intentionally this way because it garantuees that the prints are in the correct order (dicts are unordered before 3.6 so that's not garantueed otherwise). And the dictionary comprehension is unnecessarily complicated there, if that should be shorter or faster there is always `frequency = dict.fromkeys(F, 0)`

Comment: this is really good, just a question do you know why while doesn't work? I was trying variations of my code and like yours above with while, regards

Comment: @Supernova Your code didn't contain a `while` loop, so I can't say why it didn't work. Sorry.

Comment: no no problem, I only posted the code that worked when I used it with while it did not work, regards

Comment: Order was not explicitly asked to be mantained but ok, I get your point about using F as the reference to print. The second option `dict.get()` method is not needed (as you can ensure that all of the exist and none will `raise KeyError` and its actually longer and probably slower. `dict.fromkeys()` was also another option but I could just suggest one in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set to achieve this with high performance.

```
from collections import defaultdict

F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]

set_f = set(F)
freq = defaultdict(int)

for num in N:
    if num in set_f:
       freq[num] += 1

print freq
```

Ta da!

```
Out: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: 3, 4: 2, 7: 1})
```

Comment: Nice, that's the most efficient way without using Counter.

Comment: `set`s are not needed for this to work, why not keep it as a `list`?

Comment: @Adirio: If you are performing lookup, List increases time complexity. You need to use sets. Current example is a small scenario. But it is a noted programing practice to use set instead of a list for lookup.

Comment: `in` works a lot faster against `set` (O(1)) than `list` (O(n))

Comment: Creating the set from a list adds an overhead that does not get messured with just theoretical complexity evaluation. This overhead would be negligible for huge lists where the lookup time gets increased but for this case I highly doubt the overhead to be smaller than the improved lookup time.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `Counter` is highly tested, efficient and part of the STL, use it!

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4])
Counter({2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 2, 6: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1})
```

Secondly you can build your own:

```
def counter(sequence):
    counts = {}
    for item in sequence:
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1
    return counts
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> counter([2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4])
{2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1}
>>> counter([4,7,2])
{2: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1}
```

Comment: I know counter works well, I wanted to try without counter, thanks

Comment: You can make your own as I show in the second example ;) @Supernova

Answer (score 0):

you said "without using Count", so I'd say this satisfies the requirements:

```
from collections import  Counter
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
counter = Counter(N)
for n in F:
    print(n, 'occurs in N', counter[n], 'times')
```

Comment: thanks for the advice is there a way without counter? using while?

Answer (score 0):

Grouped the solutions from multiple users in this post so that they can be found easyly.

### Solution 1: `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]

times = Counter(N)

for each in F:
    print("{} occurs in N {} times".format(each, times[each]))
```

### Solution 2: `list.count()`

```
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]

for each in F:
    print("{} occurs in N {} times".format(each, N.count(each)))
```

### Solution 3: `for` loop

```
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]

times = {each: 0 for each in F}

for each in N:
    if each in times:
        times[each] += 1

for item, frequency in times.items():
    print("{} occurs in N {} times".format(item, frequency))
```